# Using annotations to return custom results in struts2

Tags: struts2, annotations, convention

I know that you can return custom objects using struts2 by specifying a  declaration in your struts.xml file.  I've done that, gotten that to work.

What I want to do is move away from that, and accomplish the same thing via annotations.  If I have an action that is going to return a custom result type I would like to be able to do it.  I played around a bit but haven't been able to get anything to work.

```
@Result(name="success", type="results.MyResult.class")
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport
{ ...
```

This doesn't work

```
@Result(name="success", type=results.MyResult.class)
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport
{ ...
```

This doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem too and have solved it.

In such case you need to add one line in `struts.xml` just like this:

```xml
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="test2"/>
<package name="test2" extends="struts-default">
  <result-types>
    <result-type name="imageResult"class="common.util.CustomizeStreamResult" />
  </result-types>
</package>
```